# Ruby's string: Escape and unescape a custom character

Tags: ruby, regex, string, escaping

Suppose I said `£` character as dangerous, and I want to be able to protect and to unprotect any string.  And vice versa.

Example 1:

```
"Foobar £ foobar foobar foobar."  # => dangerous string
"Foobar \£ foobar foobar foobar." # => protected string
```

Example 2:

```
"Foobar £ foobar £££££££foobar foobar."         # => dangerous string
"Foobar \£ foobar \£\£\£\£\£\£\£foobar foobar." # => protected string
```

Example 3:

```
"Foobar \£ foobar \\£££££££foobar foobar."        # => dangerous string
"Foobar \£ foobar \\\£\£\£\£\£\£\£foobar foobar." # => protected string
```

Is there an easy way, with Ruby, to escape (and unescape) a given character (such as `£` in my example) from a string?

**Edit: here is an explication about the behavior of this question.**

First of all, thanks for your answers. I have a Rails app with a `Tweet` model having a `content` field. Example of tweet:

```
tweet = Tweet.create(content: "Hello @bob")
```

Inside the model, there's a serialization process that converte the string like this:

```
dump('Hello @bob') # => '["Hello £", 42]'
                   # ... where 42 is the id of bob username
```

Then, I'm able to deserialize and display its tweet like this:

```
load('["Hello £", 42]') # => 'Hello @bob'
```

In the same way, it's also possible to do so with more than one username:

```
dump('Hello @bob and @joe!')        # => '["Hello £ and £!", 42, 185]'
load('["Hello £ and £!", 42, 185]') # => 'Hello @bob and @joe!'
```

That's the goal :)

But this find-and-replace could be hard to perform with something like:

```
tweet = Tweet.create(content: "£ Hello @bob")
```

'cause here we also have to escape `£` char. And I think your solution is good for this. So the result become:

```
dump('£ Hello @bob')       # => '["\£ Hello £", 42]'
load('["\£ Hello £", 42]') # => '£ Hello @bob'
```

Just perfect. <3 <3

Now, if there is this:

```
tweet = Tweet.create(content: "\£ Hello @bob")
```

I think we first should escape every `\`, and then escape every `£`, like:

```
dump('\£ Hello @bob')       # => '["\\£ Hello £", 42]'
load('["\\£ Hello £", 42]') # => '£ Hello @bob'
```

However... how can we do in this case:

```
tweet = Tweet.create(content: "\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\£ Hello @bob")
```

...where `tweet.content.gsub(/(?<!\\)(?=(?:\\\\)*£)/, "\\")` seems not working.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this?

Comment: Strings in Ruby 1.9.2 work very differently from those in 1.8.7 so you should probably specify which version you are using.

Comment: @ben-alpert: I just updated my question, about the reasons behind this behavior.

Comment: Why don't you just serialize it as `["Hello ", 42, "!"]` for `"Hello @bob!"`?

Comment: @ben-alpert: ...Wops, I've totaly right!  Many thanks for your idea.  Super simple and good way!

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully your version of ruby supports lookbehinds. If it doesn't my solution will not work for you.

Escape characters :

```
str = str.gsub(/(?<!\\)(?=(?:\\\\)*£)/, "\\")
```

Un-escape characters :

```
str = str.gsub(/(?<!\\)((?:\\\\)*)\\£/, "\1£")
```

Both regexes will work regardless of the amount of backslashes. They are complementing each other.

**Escape explanation :**

```
"
(?<!        # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind)
   \\          # Match the character “\” literally
)
(?=         # Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead)
   (?:         # Match the regular expression below
      \\          # Match the character “\” literally
      \\          # Match the character “\” literally
   )*          # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   £           # Match the character “£” literally
)
"
```

Not that I am matching a certain position. No text is consumed at all. When I pinpoint the position I want I insert a \.

**Explanation of unescape :**

```
"
(?<!        # Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below with the match ending at this position (negative lookbehind)
   \\          # Match the character “\” literally
)
(           # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   (?:         # Match the regular expression below
      \\          # Match the character “\” literally
      \\          # Match the character “\” literally
   )*          # Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\\          # Match the character “\” literally
£           # Match the character “£” literally
"
```

Here I am saving all the backslashes minus one and and I replace this number of backslashes with the special character. Tricky stuff :)

Comment: Good answer for Ruby 1.9, which has lookbehind. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ruby 1.9, which has lookbehind, then FailedDev's answer should work quite well. If you are using Ruby 1.8, which does not have lookbehind (I think), a different approach may work. Give this a try:

```rb
text.gsub!(/(\\.)|£)/m) do
    if ($1 != nil)  # If escaped anything
        "$1"        # replace with self.
    else            # Otherwise escape the
        "\\£"       # unescaped £.
    end
end
```

Note that I am not a Ruby programmer and this snippet is untested (in particular I'm not sure if the: `if ($1 != nil)` statement usage is correct -  it may need to be: `if ($1 != "")` or `if ($1)`), but I do know that this general technique (using code in place of a simple replacement string) works. I recently used this same technique for [my JavaScript solution to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7867179/nested-regex-lookahead-and-lookbehind/7867571#7867571) which was looking to find unescaped asterisks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but I think you can do a simple find-and-replace:

```
str = str.gsub("£", "\\£") # to escape
str = str.gsub("\\£", "£") # to unescape
```

Note that I changed `\` to `\\` because you have to escape the backslash in a double-quoted string.

---

**Edit:** I think what you want is a regex that matches an odd number of backslashes:

```
str = str.gsub(/(^|[^\\])((?:\\\\)*)\\£/, "\\1\\2£")
```

That does the following transformations

```
"£"       #=> "£"
"\\£"     #=> "£"
"\\\\£"   #=> "\\\\£"
"\\\\\\£" #=> "\\\\£"
```

Comment: Yup, but if the string that we want to unescape is `\\\\£`, the result is `\\£` (with a find-and-replace).  I afraid a find-and-replace can not match every possibilities.